# How to generate quickbooks request token in OAuth.I am receving bad request message

Tags: quickbooks

```
I am using the below format for generating the request token.I am getting bad request when 
using the above code.What should auth_callback should i use.
```

https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token?
    &oauth_timestamp=1202956957
    &oauth_consumer_key=123456891011121314151617181920
    &oauth_signature_method=plaintext
    &oauth_signature=abcdef
    &oauth_version=1.0
    &xoauth_lang_pref="en-us"
    &oauth_callback="http://yoursite.com/callback".

Answer (score -1):

This signature:

`&oauth_signature=abcdef`

Is no where near a valid signature.

You need to use an OAuth library, and generate a valid OAuth request and signature before you send the request to Intuit.

I also highly doubt your consumer key is correct.

Comment: Can you suggest me which OAuth library should i use both in javascript and php.

Comment: For PHP, this is what you want: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php     I don't know about Javascript (are you using Node.js? you can't really do OAuth client-side only...)